# How to Bind a Popup Window to ViewModel when using MVVM Light - BindingExpression path error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a multi-page MVVM-Light application which is working fine except for the binding in a popup window.

I have a popup window which is shown when a button in the MainWindow is clicked. This works fine, the window shows correctly when the button is clicked, but what I want to be able to do is add some buttons to the Popup window to execute some commands when the buttons are clicked, here is where I'm having issues, for some reason the XAML file is not binding with the ViewModel.

Any idea what am I missing?

I get the following warning when the Popup window shows up:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'AboutViewModel' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModelLocator'
>   (HashCode=13742435)'. BindingExpression:Path=AboutViewModel;
>   DataItem='ViewModelLocator' (HashCode=13742435); target element is
>   'AboutView' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type
>   'Object')

Here is the code I have.

### POPUP Window XMAL File

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Views.AboutView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Title="About MyApp" Height="340" Width="500"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        DataContext="{Binding AboutViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Ok" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" Content="Ok"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### POPUP ViewModel - AboutViewModel.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using MyApp.ViewModel;
using MyApp.Views;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class AboutViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public RelayCommand ExitCommand { get; private set; }

        public AboutViewModel()
        {
            ExitCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExitWindow());
        }

        private void ExitWindow()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting Window...");
        }
    }
}
```

### ViewModelLocator.cs

I'm not sure what exactly goes in here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MyApp.ViewModel;
using MyApp.Views;

namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private static MainViewModel _main;
        private static AboutViewModel _about;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
        /// </summary>
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            _main = new MainViewModel();
            _about = new AboutViewModel();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property which defines the main viewmodel.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return _main;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property which defines the main viewmodel.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public AboutViewModel About
        {
            get {
                return _about;
            }
        }
        public static void Cleanup()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your property is called `About` (not `AboutViewModel`, so I expect this to work if you change your XAML to bind to it

`DataContext="{Binding About, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`

Comment: @Subbu - Changing the DataContext to what you suggested did the trick. Post this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The DataContext source points to "Locator" which has a property "About" but in the binding it points to property "AboutViewModel". Just needs a minor correction there.